# Java JNI GDAL native library error with ClassLoader when redeploying as web application

Tags: java, c++, tomcat, java-native-interface, gdal

I'm using GDAL native library (C++ and it is installed in  /usr/lib/java/gdal). I found a trick short time ago, to allow Tomcat can load the web application and this library (cannot use System.load() or System.loadLibrary() as all will return error)

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.new_SpatialReference__SWIG_1()J
```

Then I need to use a trick to add the library path to JVM when application starts:

```
    final Field usrPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
    usrPathsField.setAccessible(true);

    // get array of paths
    final String[] paths = (String[]) usrPathsField.get(null);

    // check if the path to add is already present
    for (String path : paths) {
        if (path.equals(pathToAdd)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    //add the new path
    final String[] newPaths = Arrays.copyOf(paths, paths.length + 1);
    newPaths[newPaths.length - 1] = pathToAdd;
    usrPathsField.set(null, newPaths);
```

This works well when the Tomcat starts with application, however, if I redeploy the application, it will return error:
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/lib/java/gdal/libgdaljni.so already loaded in another classloader

I could not find any solution in StackOverflow, so I ask here if anyone can give some information. I also cannot change or add library path to environment variable or Tomcat folder, all should be done in Java code only.

Comment: Seem like it must need to create a jar and put to Tomcat lib then it can start without problem for any application which use native library, https://coderanch.com/t/474442/java/include-native-library-webservice-deployement#2127594

Answer (score 0):

So to avoid to add library to Tomcat/lib folder, I copy all the GDAL native folder to a temp directory with time stamp (e.g: /tmp/gdal_native/date.time), then I use the code above normally, except when it checks for the previous path, it will override with the new one.

```
String tmpTargetNativeFolderPath = "/tmp/gdal_native" + "/" + current date time
int i = 0;
// check if the path to add is already present
for (String path : paths) {
    String pathFolder = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(path, "/");
    if (pathFolder.equals("/tmp/gdal_native")) {
        // Override the old path with the new one
        paths[i] = tmpTargetNativeFolderPath;
        usrPathsField.set(null, paths);
        return;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Then Classloader will load the library from another folder when the web application is redeployed without the error and the usrPathsField only contains one folder path to /tmp/gdal_native/timestamp.